# Multiple file uploading with FormData and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

I'm running into an issue where I can choose multiple files fine from a form but when I check it in PHP, it only shows one file (but in the console in my browser, its showing two files) and it isn't moving the file(s) to the new location. I'm not really sure what is going on.

Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
   $('#add-items-submit').on('click', function() {
     var store_name = $('#main-store-name').text();
     var item_name = $('#add-item-name').val();
     var item_price = $('#add-item-price').val();
     var item_desc = $('#add-item-desc').val();
     var item_num = $('#add-item-number').val();

     var formData = new FormData();

     formData.append('store_name', store_name);
     formData.append('item_name', item_name);
     formData.append('item_price', item_price);
     formData.append('item_desc', item_desc);
     formData.append('item_num', item_num);

     if (document.getElementById('add-item-image') == null) {
         document.getElementById('add-items-message').value = "Please add an image of the item if you wish to submit it";
     }

     $.each($('#add-item-image')[0].files, function (i, file) {
        formData.append('item_file', file);
     });

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: '/user/add-items',
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData
     }).done(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        $('#add-items-message').html(msg.success);
     }).fail(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        $('#add-items-message').html(msg.failure);
     });
  });
```

PHP Code:

```
 public function additemsAction()
 {
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model =  new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        try {
            $store_name = $this->params()->fromPost('store_name');
            $item_name = $this->params()->fromPost('item_name');
            $item_price  = $this->params()->fromPost('item_price');
            $item_desc = $this->params()->fromPost('item_desc');
            $item_num = $this->params()->fromPost('item_num');
            $item_image = $this->params()->fromFiles('item_file');

            var_dump($item_image);

            if ($this->getUserService()->addItemsToStore($store_name, $item_name, $item_desc, $item_image, $item_num, $item_price)) {
                echo json_encode(array('success' => 'Item was successfully added to your store'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('failure' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }


    return $view_model;
}

if (!is_dir(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $this->store_name . '/items')) {
    mkdir(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id .  '/' . $this->store_name . '/items', 0777, true);
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($item_image); $i++) {
   if (is_uploaded_file($item_image['tmp_name'][$i])) {
       move_uploaded_file($item_image['tmp_name'][$i], realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $this->store_name . '/items/' . $item_image['name'][$i]);

        $this->imagick = new \Imagick(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id .  '/' . $this->store_name . '/items/' . $item_image['name'][$i]);
        // automatically enhance them
        $this->imagick->enhanceImage();

        $this->imagick->writeImagesFile(fopen(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id .  '/' . $this->store_name . '/items/' . $item_image['name'][$i], 'wb'));
   }
}
```

So, basically its not moving the files to the new location and as such executing imagick's functions on them, but I've checked my logs and no error was written in the apache logs, so I'm really confused. Oh, and I did use `var_dump` and the result was `"array(5) {↵  ["name"]=>↵  string(40) "80E0C7D8-CEB1-49E5-839F-A08F0DE798CB.jpg"↵  ["type"]=>↵  string(10) "image/jpeg"↵  ["tmp_name"]=>↵  string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php89B6.tmp"↵  ["error"]=>↵  int(0)↵  ["size"]=>↵  int(68903)↵}`

So formData is getting all the files selected but PHP is only showing one, not multiple.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i think issue is with id change this `$.each($('#add-item-image')[0].files` to class `$.each($('.add-item-image')[0].files`

Comment: I did that and now it's saying the console 
`user:517 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (user:517)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`

Comment: make sure you changed that in html too.

Comment: it has a class name already named that.

Comment: oh wait nvm, sorry

Comment: nope, var_dump is still only showing one file...

Comment: and its not moving the files.. :/

Comment: `formData.append('item_file[]', file);` make item_file array too.